# Which real British railway station features in the 1961 film The Rebel (US title: Call Me Genius) starrring Tony Hancock?

Tags: film-location, the-rebel

In the 1961 British film The Rebel (US title: Call Me Genius), Tony Hancock's character leaves his bowler-hatted life in a London office for the life of an artist in Paris. Before his decision to depart, he catches a train every morning to Waterloo station, along with a number of other men who also wear bowler hats. Which real British railway station is used as the location for where he boards the train?

(I assume it is a real station. It certainly looks real to me.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shooting location was [Bingham Road railway station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingham_Road_railway_station) in Croydon.

According to the [wikipedia article on the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rebel_(1961_film)#:%7E:text=The%20since%2Ddemolished%20railway%20station,of%20the%20English%20middle%20class.) ...

> The since-demolished railway station used at the beginning of the film, was Bingham Road in the Croydon suburb of Addiscombe, named Fortune Green South in the film.

More pictures and details about the shooting location can be found in the [Reelstreets](https://www.reelstreets.com/films/rebel-the/) page about the movie.  According to Reelstreets, the train station was closed in 1983.

Comment: It was eventually replaced with Addiscombe Tram Stop on the opposite site of the road to the station site. Also worth pointing out that you would never have been able to catch a train from Bingham Road to Waterloo!

Comment: @Muzer - You could change to a Charing Cross train at Elmers End, which called at Waterloo (East) between London Bridge and Charing Cross.